# Point domain to different server using A record

Tags: dns

I built my clients website on a subfolder on my own server.

**Example:** www.site.com/myclient

I want to add a new record on my clients domain in order to load the site from my server.
I can't change his DNS because he want's to keep his email accounts and everything on his current server.

Should I just add a new A record on his domain zone pointing to my server IP?

Answer (score 0):

One hostname can be mapped to multiple IP addresses.

Also, one hostname can be mapped to another hostname using 'CNAME' record. (Alias name record)

Mapping one IP address to multiple hostnames will cause errors.

I believe that the best solution in this scenario is to create a unique virtual (loopback) IP address in your server and map that IP to the client hostname.